# numpy: how to apply boolean index array on slice of numpy matrix cheaply

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I'm trying to apply a boolean mask array over a slice of my numpy matrix. I only figure out the following to implement this, by first copy this slice out to a single array, then apply boolean mask over this temporary array and copy it back to the matrix.

I'm wondering if there exists (sure it exists! but I can't find it) a cheaper way to implement it? a.k.a, without the cost of copying.

```
#(data is a numpy 2d matrix)

tmp = data[i,:]
tmp[tmp==0] = mean
data[i,:] = tmp
```

Comment: Can you show a sample input/output.  What is `mean`?

Comment: Take out the last line. `tmp` is a view, not a copy

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
mask = data[i,:] == 0
data[i,mask] = mean
```